# Is OAuth necessary when implementing a RESTful web application that has its own login system (no social media)?

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth, jwt

If I have a web application with a RESTful back-end that has a login system that keeps track of its own accounts (no social media logins what-so-ever), is there a point in using OAuth2 as a means of accessing the REST api? Essentially, if a login system does not have social media as a login choice, is there another route?

I have a Java-Spring back end. Would JWT be a suitable replacement for OAuth in this situation?

Comment: Hi Jake, do you mind sharing what solution you implemented and your final reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why not.

> ## When should you use JSON Web Tokens?
>
> Here are some scenarios where JSON Web Tokens are useful:
>
> - Authentication: This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the
>     JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that
>     are permitted with that token. Single Sign On is a feature that widely
>     uses JWT nowadays, because of its small overhead and its ability to be
>     easily used across different domains.
> - Information Exchange: JSON Web Tokens are a good way of securely transmitting information between parties, because as they can be
>     signed, for example using public/private key pairs, you can be sure
>     that the senders are who they say they are. Additionally, as the
>     signature is calculated using the header and the payload, you can also
>     verify that the content hasn't been tampered with.

Source: https://jwt.io/introduction/